# Escorted revived NPCs - now where have they gone?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the Inquest Outer Complex, you'll often find many revivable corpses of researchers and workers. Well, last night, I decided to liberate all these corpses. I went to each part of the complex, revived them, stuck with them, and escorted all of them out. They began to run, and ran to Luminates Plant. However, when they got there, they all just disappeared into the complex. No idea where they've gone.

Where did they go? I don't see them anywhere in the plant. Does the game have them in "stock" now to perform a raid against the Inquest later? Do they even "raid"? It feels like I've found a (mostly irrelevant) meta-game in reviving these guys and keeping them alive, and I just hope it has some effect, ulimately.

Answer (score 4):

NPCs that matter in future conflicts will stay where you can see them.

NPCs that don't matter will quickly run off-stage - they'll run until they vanish at a predetermined point.  You can even see this behavior in aggressive NPCs, such as the bandits in the Queensdale rancher event after the event is over, or the harpies in the Queensdale dam event.